# Cannot use ng-repeat with a JSON from ajax call

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, ionic-framework

i am having lots of trouble with json coming from ajax call and ng-repeat.

I have posted my code here http://jsfiddle.net/7quj9omw/ so you can view in a more organized way, although i know it is not complete, running this will just get a massive error and it contains my local url for the ajax call.

The thing is, my JSON object is retrieved fine, i can console.log(EventsService.Todos()) in my EventsController fine, it logs out a JSON object, but when passing to the ng-repeat in the markup, it wont work.

If I copy my JSON and post it directly in my code, it works fine.
I deeply think that is a parse problem, but i have already tried using PARSE.json in my variable and dont work as well.

Am I doing something wrong passing my data from my service all the way to my html markup ng repeat?

If anybody have any clues, i would be greateful, thanks.

EDIT:

there is a print of the console.log out i did in my json:
[image]

Below is an example of my JSON return:

```js
[  
   {  
      "id":"26",
      "idDeles":"zCNTdU",
      "data":"2015-02-21",
      "titulo":"Didge Steakhouse Pub ",
      "descricao":"Noite de s\u00e1bado no Didge Steakhouse Pub em Balne\u00e1rio Cambori\u00fa. ",
      "fotografo":"Mariana Haag",
      "fonte":"http:\/\/night.com.br\/fotos\/zCNTdU",
      "status":"1",
      "quantidadeFotos":"78",
      "views":"0",
      "thumb":"http:\/\/night.com.br\/arquivos\/casas\/50\/fotos\/24790\/tb\/0001_img_0020.jpg"
   },
   {  
      "id":"25",
      "idDeles":"zqNTdU",
      "data":"2015-02-21",
      "titulo":"Showbol Arena ",
      "descricao":"Noite de s\u00e1bado no Showbol Arena em Itaja\u00ed. ",
      "fotografo":"Adivasson Correa",
      "fonte":"http:\/\/night.com.br\/fotos\/zqNTdU",
      "status":"1",
      "quantidadeFotos":"165",
      "views":"0",
      "thumb":"http:\/\/night.com.br\/arquivos\/casas\/181\/fotos\/24788\/tb\/0001_img_0010.jpg"
   }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7quj9omw/2/) I downloaded the json you posted because i coudn't access to the url in the code.

```
angular.module('nightbcApp', [])
.factory('EventService', function($http, $q) {
    return {
        Todos: function() {
            var defer = $q.defer();
            $http.get("http://localhost/td.json")
                .success(function(data){
                    defer.resolve(data);
                })
                .error(function(response){
                    defer.reject(response);
                });
            return defer.promise;
        }
    };
})
.controller('EventsController', function($scope, EventService) {
    EventService.Todos().then(function(data) {
        $scope.Eventos = data;
    });
})
```

[Angular $q](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q)

Comment: you sir, deserve a cookie! it worked pretty well, just had some issues cause you misspelled Events confusing with Event (in singular) but that was nothing. I appreciate very much! It is really confusing the .then() concept for me. By now, i do not know why this works. But thanks!!!

Comment: Take a look at [this post](http://dulitha.me/blog/2014/10/08/javascript-promises-basics/) may clear some doubts

Answer (score 0):

Revised answer:

```
$http.get("http://10.1.1.5/nightbc/public/index/phonegap-eventos")
                        .success(function (response) {
                            return response.data;
                        }).error(function (response) {
                           return error;
                        });
```

Try adding .data to the response see if that works.

Comment: hi there, it returns "TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined" in the console. thanks for trying to help me

Comment: thanks for your effort, tried this too, but didnt work. josegomezr could find the right answer.

Answer (score 0):

Place a div around the a and img tag and do the repeat in there. See if that works.

Edit: I didn't catch the not assigning that would definitely be an issue. If that still doesn't work, I've had issue with the ng-repeat in tags like IMG and a so try putting those in a div and put the repeat there.

Comment: hi, tried that, i belive it is not the ng-repeat itself, since it works with my JSON directly in the code, i belive the problem is my JSON coming from the ajax call.

Comment: Try ng-repeat="event in Eventos[0]"  I think you may have nested arrays without intending to.

Comment: tried as well, although it did not work, i thought it was very clever, i belive is something like that that is crashing, i have updated my post with a print of my console.log out