# getting Angular.js to display html list of json data

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I am trying to have an HTML list of the id fields of game objects in a json file. However It does not show up in my UI. I don't know why it wont even render.

---core.js---

```
var gameapp = angular.module('gameapp',[]);

function mainController($scope,$http) {
  $scope.formData = {};

  $http.get('/api/games')
    .success(function(data){
      $scope.games = data;
      console.log(data);

    })
    .error(function(data) {
      console.log('Error' + data);
    });
}
```

---- index.html----

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="gameapp">

  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script><!-- load jquery -->
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.8/angular.min.js"></script><!-- load angular -->
  <script src="core.js"></script>

  <title>Games API</title>

  <body ng-controller="mainController">Games List:
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="game in games">
        {{ game._id }}
      </li>
    </ul>
  </body>

</html>
```

---- UI------

```
Games List:
{{ game._id }}
```

---- Here is my JSON when I type www.example.com/api/games

```
 [{"_id":"54e4add76b91eab37a3611c8","objectname":"objectname","objectid":"objectid","average":"average","avgweight":"avgweight","rank":"rank","minplayers":"minplayers","maxplayers":"maxplayers","playingtime":"playingtime","biggbestplayers":"bggbestplayers"},{"_id":"54e4add76b91eab37a3611c9","objectname":"6 qui prend !","objectid":432,"average":6.75695,"avgweight":1.2418,"rank":445,"minplayers":2,"maxplayers":10,"playingtime":45,"biggbestplayers":"5-- 6"},{"_id":"54e4add76b91eab37a3611ca","objectname":"Adel Verpflichtet","objectid":120,"average":6.40472,"avgweight":1.8605,"rank":861,"minplayers":2,"maxplayers":6,"playingtime":45,"biggbestplayers":"5-- 6"},{"_id":"54e4add76b91eab37a3611cb","objectname":"Age of Steam","objectid":4098,"average":7.53212,"avgweight":3.9285,"rank":53,"minplayers":1,"maxplayers":6,"playingtime":120,"biggbestplayers":4},{"_id":"54e4add76b91eab37a3611cc","objectname":"Agricola","objectid":31260,"average":8.06284,"avgweight":3.6088,"rank":5,"minplayers":1,"maxplayers":5,"playingtime":180,"biggbestplayers":"3-- 4"},{"_id":"54e4add76b91eab37a3611cd","objectname":"Aladdin's Dragons","objectid":492,"average":6.66519,"avgweight":2.4728,"rank":537,"minplayers":3,"maxplayers":5,"playingtime":90,"biggbestplayers":5},{"_id":"54e4add76b91eab37a3611ce","objectname":"Alexandros","objectid":8273,"average":5.86456,"avgweight":2.3423,"rank":2271,"minplayers":2,"maxplayers":4,"playingtime":45,"biggbestplayers":"NA"},{"_id":"54e4add76b91eab37a3611cf","objectname":"Alhambra","objectid":6249,"average":6.96861,"avgweight":2.1234,"rank":298,"minplayers":2,"maxplayers":6,"playingtime":60,"biggbestplayers":3},{"_id":"54e4add76b91eab37a3611d0","objectname":"Alien Frontiers","objectid":48726,"average":7.3786,"avgweight":2.541,"rank":93,"minplayers":2,"maxplayers":4,"playingtime":90,"biggbestplayers":"3-- 4"},{"_id":"54e4add76b91eab37a3611d1","objectname":"Amun-Re","objectid":5404,"average":7.21837,"avgweight":3.068,"rank":165,"minplayers":3,"maxplayers":5,"playingtime":90,"biggbestplayers":5}]
```

Comment: did u check your response? are u getting a list of games?

Comment: please show me, what is your console output

Comment: what does "console.log(data);" print??

Comment: provide us your json

Comment: we cannot see all your core.js file, but did you add the mainController function as an angular controller ? like so : app.controller('mainController' ...

Comment: that is my whole core.js file!

Comment: I checked my response and I am getting nothing

Answer (score 0):

I have a couple suggestions:

- Use a promise to load the data - [see this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28688279/1526037).
- Use the `ng-bind` directive to show the data instead of `{{game._id}}` - [see this codepen](https://codepen.io/sbolel/pen/abmXZYr)

I'd also recommend looking over:

- Angular [`$q` docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q)
- Angular [`ngBind` docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBind)

Answer (score 0):

The fact that you are getting `{{ game._id }}` printed on your page signifies there's some issue with you angular. Otherwise, it would either have not shown anything or would have shown some error on console.You might aswell have some issue in you JSON file itself.

The code looks fine otherwise. [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Lw3B8YPjQMAsmhrQBgrm?p=preview).

Also, why are you using jQuery and not using angular's jqlite? You aint using jQuery anyways.

Comment: this is the right answer! take a look at user2510809 controller and after take a look at yours:  function mainController($scope,$http) { instead of  app.controller('mainController', function($scope,$http) {

Comment: @hayatoShingu, since the OP is using Angular 1.0.8, global controller functions are allowed, and so even with `function mainController()` it works: http://plnkr.co/edit/2e1EeZTKVNINslE6h2ms?p=preview.

Comment: I'm sorry , my mistake , I was superficial . I did not notice the version of angularjs

Answer (score 0):

Try to put your `ul` inside a `div`

```
<div>
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="game in games"{{ game._id }}>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

You need to declare $scope.games variable outside success function. Means at the level where $scope.formData is declared.

Comment: The person who has marked answer as "not useful", please give me right answer.

Comment: i'm not that person, but you should consider the difference between declare and initialize

Comment: Yes, my mistake. I want to say initialize. But this could be understood from the reference of $scope.formData.

Comment: @dipendra, whether to assign `$scope.games` inside or outside of the `.success` function should not matter at all. I don't know why you came to the conclusion that it would, and in any case, you did not explain that or how it suppose to fix the problem in your answer.